# How to add block for Specific category's products in Magento 2 by layout/catalog_product_view_attribute_set_id_[id]?

Tags: magento2, xml, catalog, phtml, view

I am trying to the make block visible only in Category 3. The block renders fine in catalog_product_view.xml. However when I change the file to catalog_product_view_attribute_set_id_3.xml, it doesn't render. For my test server, id 3 is Gear, and it should render If I my approach is correct.

catalog_product_view_attribute_set_id_3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <css src="mage/gallery/gallery.css"/>
            <css src="Thevendor_Themodule::css/j_custom_bootstrap.css"/>
            <css src="Thevendor_Themodule::css/style.css"/>
        </head>
        <!--<update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />-->
        <!--<update handle="page_calendar"/>-->
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="changeproduct" template="Thevendor_Themodule::product/view/changeproduct.phtml" after="product.info.price">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Thevendor\Themodule\ViewModel\ProductLoader</argument>
                        <argument name="viewLogic" xsi:type="object">Thevendor\Themodule\ViewModel\viewLogic</argument>
    
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="showCalculator" template="Thevendor_Themodule::product/view/showCalculator.phtml" after="product.info.price">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Thevendor\Themodule\ViewModel\viewLogic</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

It renders fine when the file is named: catalog_product_view.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add some block on the base of category you need to follow the following step. By following these you will be able to achieve your requirement.

Step 1

create layout handle
vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view_id_3.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="changeproduct-text" template="vendor_module::product/view/changeproduct.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

step2 Write an observer to add your custom layout handle

vendor/module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="load_custom_handler" instance="vendor\module\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

step3 Write the Observer class and add conditional layout handle

vendor/module/Observer/LayoutLoadBefore.php

```
class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    /**
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ){
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
        if ($category) {
            if ($category->getId() == 3) { // your condition
                $layout = $observer->getLayout();
                $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_category_view_id_3');
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Magento supports only the following layout handles for product page customizations: *catalog_product_view_type_<product_type>.xml*, *catalog_product_view_id_<product_id>.xml* and *catalog_product_view_sku_<product_sku>.xml*. As you can see, attribute set id is not supported. But you can easily implement this by adding the following changes to your custom module:

1. **Add a plugin** for *Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View* class via *app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml*:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View">
           <plugin name="add-attribute-set-handler" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Helper\Product\ViewPlugin" />
       </type>
   </config>
   ```
2. **Create the plugin class** under *app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Helper/Product/ViewPlugin.php* with *beforeInitProductLayout(*) method in it :

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Helper\Product;

   use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View;
   use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
   use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
   use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page as ResultPage;

   class ViewPlugin
   {
       /**
        * @param View $subject
        * @param ResultPage $resultPage
        * @param Product $product
        * @param null|DataObject $params
        * @return array
        */
       public function beforeInitProductLayout(View $subject, ResultPage $resultPage, $product, $params = null)
       {
           $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['attribute_set_id' => $product->getAttributeSEtId()], null, false);

           return [$resultPage, $product, $params];
       }
   }
   ```

After these changes, your custom layout file should start working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show block for specifc category page, you can try with `Catalog -> Categories -> Choase 1 -> Design`

In here you can config design for only this category page!

Hope it help!